# Horrible performance on Azure App Service - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, performance

Evening All,

At by absolute wits end and hoping someone may be able to save me! I am in the process of migrating a number of PHP applications into Azure. I am using:

- Linux based App Service running PHP 7.4 (2 vCPUs, 8Gb RAM) at a cost of £94 a month.
- Azure Database on MySQL 8.0 (2 vCPUs) at £114 a month.

My PHP apps run well, decent load time of under 1 second per page. Wordpress performance however is awful. I am going from a 1 second page load to around 10 seconds, particularly on the back end. I have read all of the Azure guides and have implemented the following obvious points:

- Both the App Service and the MySQL install are in the same data center
- App Service is set to 'Always On'
- Connection Redirection is set to Preferred and tested as working

The same app runs fine on a very basic £10 or so a month shared hosting package. I have also tried the same setup in Amazon Web Services today and page load is back to a second or so.

In Chrome Console, the delay is in TTFB. I have disabled all the plugins and none stand out as making a huge difference. Each adds a second or so page load, suggesting to me a consistent issue when a page requires a number of database calls.

What is going on with Azure and the awful Wordpress performance?! Is there anything else I can investigate or try? Really keen to stay with Azure but can't cope with the huge increase in cost for a performance hit.

Comment: How is the page load time if you put a really simple HTML page on the same domain/hosting? (i.e. could the delay be network level rather than application - slow DNS servers etc?)

What does the GTMetrix.com or Lighthouse tab in Google Chrome dev tools indicate is causing the slow-down if you scan this WP site?

Comment: Just a HTML page with simple PHP call is great. No issues on that side.

Lighthouse and GTMetrix both show an exceptionally slow TTFB, at least 6 seconds or so for server response.

Comment: Sounds like the connection to the database server may be too slow for the sheer volume of sql queries Wordpress needs to generate pretty much any page...

Is your database server in the same data centre?

Optimising for Wordpress tends to be very different to optimising for other php apps as it can be so database heavy.

Comment: A work-around if you're very keen to stay on Azure and the site doesn't update drastically regularly would be to put it behind CloudFlare (they have an integration with Azure as I recall) and that extra caching and CDN power might speed things up enough to be liveable. Alternatively I'd seriously consider optimised/specialised wordpress hosting.

Comment: Thank you for both of these suggestions Steve.

Site is behind Cloudflare, which does hugely help on the front end, but any pages that require live data (a date selector for appointment times for example) are still awful. They are both in the same data centre already. 

Maybe you are right and Azure just isn't up to Wordpress yet!

Comment: Did you try to scale your MySQL db to 4 or 8 vcores, just for a quick test?

Comment: Is it solved? I have the same problem. Any Idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: Hello, it is Year 2022, I am using Azure Web App , and seperate Azure MySQL database. It is not issue about database, Wordpress Query monitor shows all fine. Except page generation time is huge. For empty worpdress site is about 1.5 seconds, and for production page with some plugins is about 5+ seconds. I do not know why is php so slow. I do have CDN, and I am not talking about static content and images. Still unable to troubleshoot why is running php so slow and still no peak in cpu graph. Any info / reference would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the way the file system runs in the app service. It is NOT an issue with the database. The App Service architecture is just too slow at present with file read/writes, of which Wordpress uses a lot. Investigated the various file cache options but none improved enough.

Ended up setting up a fairly basic, and significantly cheaper, virtual machine, running with the same database and performance is hugely improved.

Not a great answer, but App Services are not up to Wordpress at present!

Comment: how did you get to conclusion that file IO is slow? any resolution (except VM) ?

Comment: Significant testing. Exact same setup is significantly quicker on VM. There is also much documentation around the shared storage used by App Services being slow for lots of read/writes.

Comment: Did you find difference for Windows App Service and Linux App Service in compared to VM ?

Comment: I wonder how much the performance would improve if you set `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE=true` in app settings as explained at https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/KuduLite/wiki/App-Cache. This puts the application files in ephemeral storage on each app instance. User submitted files would need to be stored on a remove service like S3 https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/ but that might be worth the effort if performance significantly improves.

Comment: After quite a bit of research, I am confirming the same result.   The WordPress for Azure App Service performs terribly and is not ready for prime time.  Not sure why Azure believes it to be.  At least at their B1 or B2 pricing tiers, and any tier beyond that is well beyond reasonable for a simple WordPress instance.

Comment: I mean I've seen 5$ plan beat this App Service application up and down. Its just night and day difference. You can notice the speed of the IO by trying to download a large file from FTP - its clearly the issue.

Comment: @ShaunDychko Thank you for your comment - WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE=true solves the performance issue for me, makes the app 4x faster, there may be other issues faced including not relying on disk but this seems worth pursuing!

Comment: I do not believe WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE is an option if you need persistent storage though. If users are likely to upload files (Wordpress or similar) then this is no good. Please correct me if I am wrong??

Comment: FYI In the end I used WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false (on a Linux web app) which seems to have the same effect but without having the app run from a wierd docker volume. Either is only an option if you don't need persistent storage, so for WP you would have to have media going to blob storage/S3 and disable updates (deploy them via code).

Answer (score -2):

The comments below are correct. The "problem" is the database. You can either move MySQL to a Virtual Machine (which will give you a better performance) or you can also try to use cache plugins such as WP Super Cache as well decrease the number of requests.

You can find a full list of tips in the following link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/

PS: ignore the date, it's still relevant

Comment: Thanks Thiago, though not sure this is relevant to this case. Believe this discussion is over the database provided within the Azure Wordpress container. Our install already uses a dedicated MySQL Server.

Are you saying a VM performs better than MySQL as a service via Azure, even on the £100+ a month subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, a vm will give you a better performance.

Comment: Any reference for that at all?